# Error/Wrong Content-Type while saving image using pillow package in python on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, image-processing, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, mime-types

I'm trying to generate dimensional images using a pillow package using python. The problem I'm facing is 'Content-Type gets converting automatically to **binary/octet-stream** but my original image Content-Type is **image/jpeg**'

Here is code which I'm using to generate thumbnails

```
 def resize_image(image_path, resized_path, thumbnail_size):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail((thumbnail_size["x"], thumbnail_size["y"]))
        image.save(resized_path,"JPEG",progressive=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, problem is while uploading the file to s3 you need to specify the content-type explictly.

```
s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}'.format(bucket),
                      f'{filename}',ExtraArgs={'ContentType': '{}'.format(mimeType),'Metadata':{}})
```